# Question about VC-dimension

Tags: geometry, statistics, machine-learning, computational-geometry

Because I'm not used to the theorem of VC-dimension, I don't know why these statements hold.

Why **axis parallel square can shatter a set of three points?**

and **can't shatter any set of four points?**

Comment: you mean the class of all axis parallel squares or a particular one? (it does not change the answer, but makes it more precise).

Comment: yes system of axis parallel squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $3$ points that form triangle, it should be clear that you can enclose every point with an square, you just have to make it as small as you need and it is also clear that there must happen that $x_1\leq x_2<x_3$ with either $x_1<x_2$ or $x_2<x_3$(because they are collinear) so you can separate two points.

The problem with $4$ points is that if they are collinear, and you order them somehow in that line say by $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4,$ then is not possible to have $x_1,x_3$ separated from $x_2,x_4.$ Because $x_2$ has to lie in any square containing $x_1,x_3.$

Comment: Oh. I understand your answer thanks.
So shattering is by the system, it is able to divide points with all possible subset?

Comment: @Ronald, you are welcome.

Comment: Thank you again!!

Comment: I'm looking carefully your answer again, and I have one question that I missed. If three points are collinear, and denote those three points $v_1,v_2,v_3$ with ordering $v_1<v_2<v_3$(Appearing order of half-line). If we want to separate subset $\{v_1,v_3\}$, how can we select proper square?

Comment: @Ronald You are right. I was wrong with the definition. The definition is not for all sets. Is the existance of a set. So, you need just **one** configuration of points A in which for every subset $B$, there exists $c\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $B=A\cap c.$